# Check full binary tree mistake

Tags: c++

I have a function to check whether the tree is full tree or not:

```
int checkfull(plant* root){
    if (root == NULL)
        return 1;
    else if (root->pLeft == NULL && root->pRight == NULL)
        return 1;
    else if ((root->pLeft == NULL && root->pRight != NULL) || (root->pLeft != NULL && root->pRight == NULL))
        return 0;
    else
        return (checkfull(root->pLeft) && checkfull(root->pRight));
}
```

But the problem is if the tree is like this:

[image]

the return is 1 and i don't know why?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Does your input really have the structure in the picture or are you just assuming that it does?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your debugger, the algorithm is doing the job as excepted and return 0.
Here is my test code with a suspected tree (I added a sID parameter to identify the node as dsiplayed):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct splant {
    struct splant *pLeft;
    struct splant *pRight;
    char *sId;
} plant;

int checkfull(plant* root){
    if (root == NULL)
        return 1;
    else if (root->pLeft == NULL && root->pRight == NULL)
        return 1;
    else if ((root->pLeft == NULL && root->pRight != NULL) || (root->pLeft != NULL && root->pRight == NULL))
        return 0;
    else
        return (checkfull(root->pLeft) && checkfull(root->pRight));
}

int main()
{
    plant p0103[] = { NULL, NULL, "0103" };
    plant p0141[] = { NULL, NULL, "0141" };
    p0141->pLeft = p0103;
    plant p0900[] = { NULL, NULL, "0900" };
    plant p0863[] = { NULL, NULL, "0863" };
    p0863->pRight = p0900;
    plant p0523[] = { NULL, NULL, "0523" };
    p0523->pLeft = p0141;
    p0523->pRight = p0863;

    int iRes = checkfull(p0523);

    return (0);
}
```